# How do I pull the user profile of the logged in user? django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django's built in User model and this UserProfile model.

```
# this is model for user profile
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
   .
   .
   .
   general attributes
```

How can I check if the logged in user has an associated user profile and pass the bool value in the context_dict?

I need that to decide whether to show "Create Profile" or "Edit Profile" in the homepage. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to fetch the profile, you can use `hasattr`, and avoid the need for exception handling.

```
user_has_profile = hasattr(user,  'profile')
```

In a view, `request.user` is the logged in user so you would do

```
user_has_profile = hasattr(request.user,  'profile')
```

Comment: I already noticed cases where `obj.related` was `None`. I didn't try to figure out when and why though.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `related_name='profile'`. So you can do:

```
def has_profile(user):
    try:
        return user.profile is not None
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

As a generic way to check if a model has a related, you can do:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def has_related(obj, field_name):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, field_name) is not None
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return False
```

Comment: That's really great thank you. However, I'm a bit new to django so do I put this function under the UserProfile model? and how do I eventually pass the value in context_dict. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can put this function as UserProfile method. In this case, name the first argument `self`, not `obj`. Otherwise you can put it in a `utils` model for instance.

Comment: thank you. and how do i call this function in views in order to have a variable with either True or False?

Comment: I don't understand your question. This function already returns True or False. Just call it as you would call any other function (or method).