# how to redirect to a profile page and see the data of the logged in user in Django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have been working on a small project, and it was developing smoothly until I got a road block. However, I am not able to route to the profile page. 
My website workflow is as below:

```
1) user sign up and redirect to login screen once registration successful.
2) user login and now he/she sees a form, where he/she needs to fill in mandatory fields
3) save and then either click on "profile" link(in the navbar) to see the profile data, or "save" button will redirect to the profile page automatically.
```

point 3) is not working. For now I have a hyperlink in the NavBar for "profile". But its not doing anything though I have written the GET method. May be I am not fetching the data properly.

I have gone through couple of web link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445230/how-to-redirect-to-user-profile-page-after-log-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083945/how-do-i-pull-the-user-profile-of-the-logged-in-user-django) within the Stackoverflow, but they solutions not working for me

Below are my django files details:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import SignUpForm, UserProfileForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'login success')
            return redirect('bolo')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'error while login, please try again')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate\\login.html', {})
```

I also found that we can use @login_required decorator. So, I have implemented it as below on the method that is written to GET data from database

```
@login_required
def profile_page(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.GET:
        form = UserProfileForm()
        sec_data = UserProfile.objects.all()
        context = {'form': form, 'sec_data': sec_data}
    else:
        return redirect('bolo')
    return render(request, 'authenticate\\profile.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home, login_user, logout_user, register_user, userProfileView, profile_page

urlpatterns = [
    path("home/", home, name='home'),
    path("login/", login_user, name='login'),
    path("logout/", logout_user, name='logout'),
    path("register/", register_user, name='register'),
    path("bolo/", userProfileView, name='bolo'),
    path('profile/', profile_page, name='profile'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Photo = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=20, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

profile.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}

    <!--<form method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->
    <title>User Detailed Profile</title>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% for data in sec_data %}
                Photo:
                <p><img src = {{ data.image.url }} width="200" height="200" /></p>
                <p>DOB:{{ data.dob }}</p>
                <p>Country: {{ data.country }}</p>
                <p>State: {{ data.State }}</p>
                <p>District: {{ data.District }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}

        {% endif %}

    <!--</form>-->
    {{data.errors}}
    {% endblock %}

base.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Django People</title>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark">
    <div class="container"python >
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item active">

      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
    </li>
     {% else %}
    <li class="nav-item active">

      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8">
          <h1 class="mt-2">Django People</h1>
          <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
```

Please help, thank you.

added latest error as below:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/
User has no userprofile.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no userprofile.
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import UserProfile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

New Error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/
User has no userprofile.
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version:
3.0.5
Exception Type:
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
User has no userprofile.
Exception Location:
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py in __get__, line 420
Python Executable:
C:\Python38\python.exe
Python Version:
3.8.2
Python Path:
['C:\\Users\\anshu\\djago-project\\SkoolSkill',
 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Python38',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:
Sat, 2 May 2020 09:08:02 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're checking the request.GET in your profile_page view and this is returning false. This means the context isn't being created and passed to the render function (I would expect an error to be thrown when trying to access the page).

```
@login_required
def profile_page(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.GET: # remove this line and the if/else
        form = UserProfileForm()
        sec_data = UserProfile.objects.all()
        context = {'form': form, 'sec_data': sec_data}
    else:
        return redirect('bolo')
    return render(request, 'authenticate\\profile.html', context)
```

Edit: The second error is occurring because the UserProfile doesn't yet exist, you can either prevent the page from being accessed when the UserProfile doesn't exist or automatically create the profile when the User is saved, example below.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Ok, so please let me know what do you suggest?

Comment: Remove the if-statement that is checking request.GET

Comment: So, now the page is getting rendered, but instead of displaying just the logged in user's data, the page is fetching data of all other users as well. How to restrict this view, so that the logged in user could see just their data?

Comment: Ah, that would be due to your `sec_data = UserProfile.objects.all()` line, you can get data for just the current user via `request.user.userprofile`

Comment: I assigned "request.user.userprofile" to sec_data, if that is what you meant. But I am getting an error. Just updated the original post with it. please check.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access the UserProfile before it exists - not sure how you want to approach that but one solution is to use signals (see my edited response)

Comment: Ok, I will implement it and let you know. In the mean time, are you sure we don't need to do any modifications in login view?

Comment: Implemented the signals, and still the same error. updated the original query with the signals code and the error.

Comment: Can you tell me which one is line 71 in your views.py? That's what the error is pointing to

Comment: to test, I had added "if user.is_authenticated". So, removed it, and I gpt the same error even if the signal is there. If you are comfortable, can we chat in stackoverflow, as the post is getting bigger.

Comment: Now the data is coming on the profile page. There were many syntax error in HTML. Fixed that now its showing up. Now the only difference is, the default fields those coming from User model(email, first_name, and last_name) is only coming. The remaining fields(photo, dob, country) for which I had created the custom model is not showing data. Would you want to help here for that, or should I open a new query?

Comment: The errors are fixed. So thread could be concluded. I will open a new thread for another issue